# Почему программа считает 89 раз вместо 22

Tags: java

```java
public class Main {
    public static final String TEXT = "aaababaabaaaabaabaabaabaaababaabaaababaabaaaabaabaabaabbabaabaaababaababaabaabaabaaabbaab";
    public static final String PATTERN = "aab";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < TEXT.length(); i++) {
            if (TEXT.charAt(i) == PATTERN.length()) {
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Строка " + PATTERN + " встретилась в тексте " + count + " раз");
    }
}
```

Comment: Укажите [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1476588/edit), какой ожидаемый результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: 15 раз в тексте

Comment: 1) `PATTERN.length()` всегда равно числу `3`. 2) У вас пустой `if`, который не несет смысла. 3) Ваша программа прибавляет `counter` на каждый раз в цикле, то есть попросту считает количество символов в строке, поэтому результат `89`. 4) Неизвестно, что должна делать ваша программа и как получить число `15`, так как в вопросе нет условия задачи, [добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1476588/edit) описание задачи в вопрос.

Comment: тут не 15 вхождений

Answer (score 1):

Следует искать индекс вхождения строки при помощи `String::indexOf(String sub, int from)`:

```java
int count = 0;

int pos = 0;
while ((pos = TEXT.indexOf(PATTERN, pos)) != -1) {
    count++;
    pos += PATTERN.length();
}

System.out.println("Строка " + PATTERN + " встретилась в тексте " + count + " раз");
```

Однако, даже в таком случае будет найдено 22 вхождения.

---

Аналогично, можно построить регулярное выражение из шаблона `PATTERN` и подсчитать число совпадений:

```java
System.out.println("Строка " + PATTERN + " встретилась в тексте " +
        Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(PATTERN))
                .matcher(TEXT).results().count() 
        + " раз"
);
```

В обоих случаях будет напечатано:

```
Строка aab встретилась в тексте 22 раз
```