# Как сохранить все снимки с Api NASA за январь 2022г?

Tags: java, json, api, for, while

//Задание 11. Сохраните все снимки NASA за январь 2022 года.

Не могу понять как с помощью цикла пройтись по json и сохранить
каждую картинку в отдельный файл, создать файлы получилось, а сохраняется
всего одна картинка самая первая во все файлы.

```
    String result = downloadWebPage("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=2022-1-3&api_key=DEMO_KEY");
```

//        System.out.println(result);

```
    for (int i = 1; i < result.length(); i++) {

        int quiteStart = result.indexOf("img_src");
        int quiteEnd = result.indexOf("earth_date");


        String str = result.substring(quiteStart + 10, quiteEnd - 3);

        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println("Картинка сохранена");

        String s = Integer.toString(i) + ".jpg";
        try (InputStream in = new URL(str).openStream()) {
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get(s)  );
        }

    }
}
private static String downloadWebPage(String url) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();

    try (InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    }

    return result.toString();

}
```

}

Comment: А вы где-то меняете `result` внутри цикла?  У вас в цикле _для каждого символа_ ищется _первое вхождение подстрок `img_src` и `earth_date`_ в неизменяемой строке `result`.  Какой результат вы ожидаете?  И почему не пользуетесь стандартными парсерами JSON в виде библиотек Jackson, Gson и т.п.?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему программа считает 89 раз вместо 22](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476588/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-89-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-22)

Comment: Еще один кандидат  в дубликаты [Как вырезать часть строки до и после определённых символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1484294/)

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас JSON-строка, содержащая несколько вхождений ключа `"image_src"`, и нужно извлечь все значения данного ключа, то *правильнее* было бы распарсить такую строку при помощи какой-либо из библиотек для работы с JSON, и затем обработать полученную коллекцию / массив объектов.

Но если есть желание "наколхозить" некоторое решение стандартными средствами Java, можно обойтись регулярным выражением, чтобы искать строку с известным префиксом:

```java
// import java.util.*;
// import java.util.regex.*;
// import java.util.stream.*;

public static List<String> getImageUrls(String json) {
    return Pattern.compile("\"image_src\":\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"")
        .matcher(json)
        .results() // Stream<MatchResult>
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Аналогично можно "распарсить" входную строку вручную при помощи методов обработки строк `String::indexOf`, `String::substring`:

```java
// import java.util.*;

public static List<String> getImageUrls(String json) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    int pos = 0;
    
    while ((pos = json.indexOf("\"image_src\":", pos)) != -1) {
        pos += "\"image_src\":".length();        // пропустить префикс
        int start = json.indexOf("\"", pos) + 1; // открывающая кавычка
        int end = json.indexOf("\"", start);     // закрывающая кавычка
        result.add(json.substring(start, end));  
        pos = end;                               // обновить позицию поиска
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Тесты:

```java
System.out.println(getImageUrls("[{\"img.src\":\"aaa.jpg\"}, {\"img.src\": \"b001.png\"}]"));
System.out.println(getImageUrls("[{\"image_src\":\"aaa.jpg\"}, {\"image_src\": \"b001.png\"}]"));
```

Вывод результатов:

```
[]
[aaa.jpg, b001.png]
```